how to get last time paymentintent failed by passing paymentIntent id in stripe
I am currently showing payment Failure info in my system.
I want to show last payment failed timeStamp for payments.
How to do it using paymentIntentId?
Here is a code I tried,
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.retrieve(
        paymentIntentId
        );
        let error = paymentIntent.last_error


but,It doesn't give me timestamp
how to get time at which paymentIntent failed?

Actually, you can retrieve the charge of the last_payment_error of the payemnt intent and then fetch the creation date of the charge.
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_...');

const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.retrieve(
  'pi_...', {
    expand: ['last_payment_error.chage']
  }
);
paymentIntent?.last_payment_error?.charge?.created

